# Actual and formal argument lists differ in length (but both lengths are 2?)

Tags: java, constructor, compiler-errors

[image]

Hello. While trying to compile a simple Java class, i have found that i get an error that tells me the "actual" and "formal" arguemnt lists differ in length. However, i've only made constructors for the "Prosessor" class that are of argument length 2, and I'm only trying to construct it using argument lengths of 2 as well. Does anyone know what my mistake could be?

Comment: Pseudo-constructor warning!

Comment: read if your Processor class imported is the good (your method) and remove "void" word!!

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a method, not a constructor.

A constructor has no return type. Remove the `void` keyword.

Because you haven't defined any constructors, your class currently has the default, zero-parameter constructor, so your use of a two-parameter constructor is invalid.

Comment: Thank you. That's quite a blunder on my part.